# Not able to enable JMX for Grizzly

Tags: java, jmx, grizzly

I tried enabling the JMX for grizzly server. I added the gmbal-api-only-3.1.0 jar file to the project and wrote the following simple code :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpServer gws = new HttpServer();
        NetworkListener listener1 = new NetworkListener("listener1", "localhost", 19080);
        gws.addListener(listener1);
        try {
            gws.start();
            gws.getServerConfiguration().setJmxEnabled(true);
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            try {
                gws.stop();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }  
}
```

I ran this program and opened it up in the JConsole, but the JConsole do not show any MBean for the grizzly server in spite of using `setJMXEnabled(true)`.

Please tell me what could be missing here or what is wrong with the code? Else, please suggest how to enable JMX for grizzly and how to verify it. I tried using the "Grizzly HTTP JMX Server Monitoring" approach given on the link : https://grizzly.java.net/monitoring.html

Comment: did you add grizzly-framework-monitoring, gmbal-api-only and gmbal jars in you class path?

Comment: Yes, I added them into the classpath as well.